# Custom Post Types UI paragraph style

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a paragraph tag with a specific class and I want to put the_content inside of it. The problem I have is that after actually creating the record the_content() is just in a

tag and not inside my  tag. How can I fix this? I am using the CPT UI plugin.

```
<p class="lead"> <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what the output HTML looks like?

Comment: It just shows the class as empty and then below it, the content is in the plan <p> tags e.g.: `<p class="lead"></p><p>Content here instead of in lead class paragraph tag</p>`

Comment: `the_content()` is already in paragraphs, and you can't nest `<p>` tags. Either make `lead` a `div` or `section` or use a different field than `the_content()` for this content.

Comment: I created a <div class="lead"> and put the_content() in there. That seems to have sorted it out. Thanks! I can't seem to give you an up vote for your comment.